# Navigation with nested list: Screen reader support for list labels and nesting level

Tags: html, accessibility, nested-lists, wai-aria, screen-readers

**What is best practice to enhance the semantic accessibility of a website `<nav>` landmark with a nested `<ul>` list for screen reader users?** (aria-label and list level are currently not pronounced by all screen readers)

I tested with Voiceover on iOS 9, Talkback on Android 5 and NVDA 2016-1 on Win10 (in Firefox). I used (mostly) default settings in the screen reader applications.

I thought the following list should be optimal prepared for screen reader users:

**Demo code 1**

```html
<nav>
  <ul aria-label="product navigation">
    <li><a href="product-a.html">Product A</a>
      <ul aria-label="sub menu Product A">
        <li><a href="product-a-spec.html">Specifications</a></li>
        <li><a href="product-a-acce.html">Accessories</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="product-b.html">Product B</a>
      <ul aria-label="sub menu Product B">
        <li><a href="product-b-spec.html">Specifications</a></li>
        <li><a href="product-b-acce.html">Accessories</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Expected result: Screen reader say something like this:

> - Beginning of navigation landmark
> - Beginning list **level 1** *"product navigation"* with two elements
> - *"Product A"* link
> - Beginning list **level 2** *"sub menu Product A"* with two elements
> - *"Specifications"* link
> - *"Accessories"* link
> - End of list **level 2** *"sub menu Product A"*
> - *"Product B"* link
> - Beginning list **level 2** *"sub menu Product B"* with two elements
> - *"Specifications"* link
> - *"Accessories"* link
> - End of list **level 2** *"sub menu Product B"*
> - End of list **level 1** *"product navigation"*
> - End navigation landmark

I also expected detailed info when touching sub menu items on table/phone, e.g.

> - *"Specifications"* link **level 2** list *"sub menu Product B"*

But unfortunately this is not working in Voiceover, Talkback or NVDA.

### The list labels and the list level are both not spoken.

When using a screen reader and jumping from list to list (like using `l` key or the list rotator/navigation) you have no idea, what list you're in. In case the elements of the children lists have similar links (like in the demo code) this problem seems for me to be even worse.

I also think it is very confusing (at least for me) to hear "beginning of list" and "end of list" multiple times with no hint, what kind of list is beginning or ending - especially when you are on a mobile or tablet and discovering the display content randomly with your finger.

I made a test series and tried different variations, e.g. I added explicit `role="list"` and `"listitem"`. I also added `aria-level="1"` and `"2"` to the listitems as shown in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11131648/1843159) - without success. **Are list levels supported by any screen reader software?**

One of my findings: At least Voiceover (on iOS) is telling the aria-label of the `<ul>` elements, but only when defining explicit `role="list"` like in the following code. **But this also only works when the `<nav>` container is not used** - Voiceover (on iOS) is ignoring the fact that there is a list completely when using `<ul>` within `<nav>`. So when using a `<nav>` landmark the list is gone in Voiceover and also not accessible via the rotator/list navigator.

**Demo code 2**

```html
<ul role="list" aria-label="product navigation">
  <li role="listitem"><a href="product-a.html">Product A</a>
    <ul role="list" aria-label="sub menu Product A">
      <li role="listitem"><a href="product-a-spec.html">Specifications</a></li>
      <li role="listitem"><a href="product-a-acce.html">Accessories</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li role="listitem"><a href="product-b.html">Product B</a>
    <ul role="list" aria-label="sub menu Product B">
      <li role="listitem"><a href="product-b-spec.html">Specifications</a></li>
      <li role="listitem"><a href="product-b-acce.html">Accessories</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I think when using a nested list it is important to tell the blind user the nesting level and the list label (at least for the sub level lists, so you know that it is a sub level list) - is there currently a way to solve this?

In case it is not possible, I'd say that it is not a good advice to use nested lists in `<nav>` for navigation... or nested lists at all?

**Edit 1:** Updated demo code

**Edit 2:** More findings

In [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32971759/1843159) is made clear, that there are no fixed rules about how screen reader should handle/read aria-label.

`<nav>` and `<ul>` are grouping elements - according to the answer the labels are more likely to be read - unfortunately not in my tests when there are nested lists in a navigation landmark.

I also found a [page listing some screen reader test results for unordered nested lists](http://maxdesign.com.au/jobs/sample-accessibility/03-lists/04-nested.html) - at the beginning they state what "should be announced", so it's optional. :/ The Voiceover results of this page are not valid for Voiceover on iOS 9, the nesting level is not announced in my test.

On the NVDA GitHub issue tracker there are also [multiple discussions about the way to implement support for aria-label](https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues/1354). And I also found this long but really interessting article about [the ridiculous complicated world of aria-label](http://blog.jantrid.net/2015/12/woe-aria-surprisingly-but-ridiculously.html).

Anyway, so now I know I can't expect that nesting levels or aria-labels are announced by default. I'm still wondering if there is a way to enhance accessibility for blind users when the screen reader software doesn't support this functionality...

Comment: Thank you for all the answers! I'd like to split the bounty to all given answers but unfortunately that is not possible. So congratulations @stringy, you have the most votes for your answer. It is hard to decide which answer should be marked as the "solution" to the question. If you are a accessibility/usability expert or a blind user please feel free to add your experience and suggestion as well! Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I know there are some people on Stack Overflow who use screenreader software everyday by necessity, while I only use it for testing. So if any of them contradict my answer, go with their suggestions.

But to me, all the additional ARIA you want to add would just make the menu longer to listen to. The content itself is what makes it clear these are submenus (when there is real content and not example content), so there is no need for aria-label attributes. It's confusing for you, but remember that you only use a screenreader on the sites you build, not every site. Being consistent with the rest of the web's navigation helps people understand your site more quickly.

Also, ARIA roles as in your second example are intended to change the way HTML elements are reported to screenreaders (e.g. A div which behaves like a button). Since you are adding matching roles, you are increasing your workload without adding usability for anyone.

So using semantically correct HTML is all you need to do in this case to make a perfectly accessibile menu. There is no need to add ARIA until you are building unusual widgets, not standard links and text.

Comment: I expected an answer like this and agree mostly. But are nested lists really so badly supported by screen readers? I updated my example code, imagine a longer list with similar sub menu items and also more nesting levels... currently I would say such a list is unusably for screen reader users, especially when the screen readers don't recognice them as list because they are in a <nav> element...

Comment: Yeah, mega menus are awful for screenreader users. I usually recommend against having them, because there are usability problems for sighted users as well. I think Firefox/NVDA will recognise lists in nav elements, and JAWS/IE. But I haven't checked that lately.

Answer (score 2):

You won't help users by giving them the nesting level number, or ask them to remember the menu section they are into.

If you really want to help the users, tell them where they are everywhere.
See https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/navigation-mechanisms-link.html

```
<nav>
   <h2>Product navigation</h2>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="product-a.html">Product A</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="product-a-spec.html" title="Specifications of Product A">Specifications</a></li>
        <li><a href="product-a-acce.html" title="Accessories for Product A">Accessories</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="product-b.html">Product B</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="product-b-spec.html" title="Specifications of Product B">Specifications</a></li>
        <li><a href="product-b-acce.html" title="Accessories for Product B">Accessories</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

You can use the `title` attribute conjointly with the `aria-label` attribute in order to be compatible with the majority of screenreaders and be accessible for non-screenreaders users.

Comment: Thank you for the w3 link! Interessting notes about different "pro/con long link text" user groups. Maybe your way combined with a link-textlenght-switch at the page top could be a way to an optimal approach...

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're not getting the labels read out is because you have them as `arial-label` instead of `aria-label` in your code. If you change this to aria-label they will be read as the screenreader is going through the document. If you are tabbing through the links, however, the aria label of the list element will not be read as it's not a focusable element. The screenreader should handle the nesting properly without the need for additional labelling - I've tested this in NVDA and it works as expected - it will announce 'list with two items' when I tab from 'Product A' into "specifications'. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Of course it is `aria-label` (I updated the question, had this typo only here in the demo code on stackoverflow, not in my personal test series, so my findings are still valid). +1 for the hint with "If you are tabbing through the links, however, the aria label of the list element will not be read as it's not a focusable element". But unfortunately your test result with NVDA confirms my finding. The list is announced in NVDA, yes, but not the list level (and as lists are not interactive also not the list labels)

Comment: aria labels are only applicable to focusable elements, so to achieve what you've described you might be better replacing it with aria-describedby.
This would require placing an ID such as `<ul id="foo">` and reference it like: `<li><a aria-describedby="foo" href="product-a.html">Product A</a>`